# How to drag control around like Tinder vote? (see images)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

There is obviously a view with uiimage view and uilabel.

how to make the dragging understand moving right to enable a positive vote and moving left a negative one?

[image]

[image]

[Tinder](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tinder/id547702041?mt=8)

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/nickypatson/TinderSwipeView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a great article: http://guti.in/articles/creating-tinder-like-animations/

The code is available on Github:
https://github.com/ngutman/TinderLikeAnimations

**[Update 1]**
Since this question is getting quite some views, thought I'd update this answer with a link to more recent library aimed at solving this problem:
https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose

[image]

**[Update 2]**

https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableView

[image]

Comment: I built a slightly more comprehensive project based on what he did that focuses on how customizability of the feel of the cards (how they move and stuff).  Might not be helpful, but might as well throw it out there: https://github.com/cwrichardkim93/TinderSimpleSwipeCards

Comment: anything like the first one in android??

Comment: Downvoted as initial link with actual answer has vanished. Provide actual answers on StackOverflow, not links.

Answer (score 3):

use two gesture recognizers, and assign one to left swipes and one to rigt swipes. then you can react accordingly to the gestures. or do you need a panning gesture? thats slightly more complicate, as you need the direction of the movement, i.e. a negative value is left, and a positive value is right. ask if you have problems with this, heres a link to a great tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more
and heres the class ref for pangesturerecongnizers. you want the -translationInView: method.
it will return the point your view was dragged to. now determine if it was left or right, and react.