# Tinder app animation (Drag and Drop of view or layout ) in Android

Tags: android, animation, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop a Layout like Tinder App like drag and Drop.How to do it? please   reply me. [image: For like picture]
[image: Unlike Picture]

Solved

Step 2. Create Activity for Drag Drop View Like MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dragdropviewdemo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int windowwidth;
int screenCenter;
int x_cord, y_cord;
int Likes = 0;
RelativeLayout parentView;
float alphaValue = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
    parentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutview);
    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    screenCenter = windowwidth / 2;
    int[] myImageList = new int[] { R.drawable.event1, R.drawable.event2,
            R.drawable.event3, R.drawable.event4, R.drawable.event5,
            R.drawable.event6 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        final RelativeLayout myRelView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        myRelView
                .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((windowwidth - 80), 300));
        myRelView.setX(40);
        myRelView.setY(40);
        myRelView.setTag(i);
        myRelView.setBackgroundResource(myImageList[i]);

        if (i == 0) {
            myRelView.setRotation(-1);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            myRelView.setRotation(-5);

        } else if (i == 2) {
            myRelView.setRotation(3);

        } else if (i == 3) {
            myRelView.setRotation(7);

        } else if (i == 4) {
            myRelView.setRotation(-2);

        } else if (i == 5) {
            myRelView.setRotation(5);

        }

        final Button imageLike = new Button(this);
        imageLike.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 50));
        imageLike.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.stamp_liked));
        imageLike.setX(20);
        imageLike.setY(80);
        imageLike.setAlpha(alphaValue);
        imageLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

            //your like action code write here 
           }
          });
        myRelView.addView(imageLike);

        final Button imagePass = new Button(this);
        imagePass.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 50));
        imagePass.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.pass));

        imagePass.setX((windowwidth - 200));
        imagePass.setY(100);
        imagePass.setRotation(45);
        imagePass.setAlpha(alphaValue);
        imagePass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            //your pass action code write here 
            }
         });
        myRelView.addView(imagePass);

        myRelView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                myRelView.setX(x_cord - screenCenter + 40);
                myRelView.setY(y_cord - 150);
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                    myRelView.setX(x_cord - screenCenter + 40);
                    myRelView.setY(y_cord - 150);
                    if (x_cord >= screenCenter) {
                        myRelView
                                .setRotation((float) ((x_cord - screenCenter) * (Math.PI / 32)));
                        if (x_cord > (screenCenter + (screenCenter / 2))) {
                            imageLike.setAlpha(1);
                            if (x_cord > (windowwidth - (screenCenter / 4))) {
                                Likes = 2;
                            } else {
                                Likes = 0;
                            }
                        } else {
                            Likes = 0;
                            imageLike.setAlpha(0);
                        }
                        imagePass.setAlpha(0);
                    } else {
                        // rotate
                        myRelView
                                .setRotation((float) ((x_cord - screenCenter) * (Math.PI / 32)));
                        if (x_cord < (screenCenter / 2)) {
                            imagePass.setAlpha(1);
                            if (x_cord < screenCenter / 4) {
                                Likes = 1;
                            } else {
                                Likes = 0;
                            }
                        } else {
                            Likes = 0;
                            imagePass.setAlpha(0);
                        }

                        imageLike.setAlpha(0);
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                    Log.e("X Point", "" + x_cord + " , Y " + y_cord);
                    imagePass.setAlpha(0);
                    imageLike.setAlpha(0);

                    if (Likes == 0) {
                        Log.e("Event Status", "Nothing");
                        myRelView.setX(40);
                        myRelView.setY(40);
                        myRelView.setRotation(0);
                    } else if (Likes == 1) {
                        Log.e("Event Status", "Passed");
                        parentView.removeView(myRelView);
                    } else if (Likes == 2) {

                        Log.e("Event Status", "Liked");
                        parentView.removeView(myRelView);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        parentView.addView(myRelView);

    }

}
```

}

use this xml 
Step 1. Create layout xml for my activity view like mainlayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: I havnt used the Tinder app, can we please elaborate your need with some screen shots or more desc.

Comment: i want to like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381486/how-to-drag-control-around-like-tinder-vote-see-images

Comment: relative layout is drag but not rotate relative layout like tinder app like and nope view in my app.

Comment: @GrIsHu hi, please see my solution, 1> create xml file and 2> create MainActivity.java class and run it's work for me

Comment: so did you find any exact solution for this?

Comment: this is solution for that but you found any solution to replay or give answer

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code. Why is it slow when the relative layout we are moving is above the stack of layouts? when only two layouts remains in the stack its good but more than two its slow?

Comment: i will check and update code again bro... and you will found another good solution reply.

Comment: How can we move image from like and nope buttons, can any one tell me the logic pls

Comment: how to provide button action of like and nope in android, can please provide logic for me......

Comment: please add like and pass button click event before this this in code myRelView.addView(imageLike); and myRelView.addView(imagePass);

Comment: Hey @VijayRajput please provide me demo code we are working one project which have same photo slider like Tinder please help me dear

Comment: @BhaveshNai pelase see my solution

Comment: @BhaveshNai https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards , https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

Comment: @BhaveshNai above code in my question is solution of this question so implement in your app and run it working

Comment: @VijayRajput i use your code . but i need same frame of all cards.

Comment: dont display below card. if user swipe card then display second card. otherwise not. Just solve frame issue.

Comment: ok i will send updated code as soon as posible

Comment: @VijayRajput how to use pass, info and like button below the cards?

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal hi create card with out buttons and add buttons in     mainlayout.xml relatiview layout.

Comment: @VijayRajput how to find id of top view so that swipe animation can be performed or on click of detail button can view detail of that top view?

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal in my case i stored all cards detail in array and than after call for loop and add cards in view so using arraylist last index give you card id.

Comment: @VijayRajput in this you have just used image how it can be used for custom cards layout view ?

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal sorry for reply you are create one layout file for card and inflate that card layout in view View mCardView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, null);  parentView.addView(mCardView );

Comment: @VijayRajput Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68330/discussion-between-himanshu-agarwal-and-vijay-rajput).