# Tinder like app view with Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, swipeview

I have requirement to develop the view which is same like in [Tinder App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinder) in play store.

I have already gone through the [same Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757039/tinder-app-animation-drag-and-drop-of-view-or-layout-in-android) but it did not helped me.
Also checked the [TinderLikeAnimations library](https://github.com/ngutman/TinderLikeAnimations) which is available for iOS not for Android.

Does anyone know such kind of library available for Android platform ?

Please help me for this if anyone came across such kind of requirement.

Thanks

Comment: @Kedarnath I have knowledge of it. But i want it in Android only. Do not want to go for cross platform. I have mentioned that in question.

Comment: I have created control on my own. If anyone need it then check out http://grishma102.blogspot.in/

Comment: @grishu: Sounds interesting, but could you give an exact link? Couldn't find it on your blog.

Comment: @Nilzor Check out the Demo here. https://github.com/Grishu/Swipeable-Cards

Comment: Thanks a lot @grishu, I'll chceck it out. Don't understand why this question was closed.

Comment: you may try swipecard library from github https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards